# Equivalent definitions of a regular element in an algebraic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$.  I'd like to see that the following two definitions are equivalent.

1. An element $g\in G$ is regular if $\dim(C_G(g))$ is minimal.
2. An element $g\in G$ is regular if $\dim(C_G(g))=\mathrm{rank}(G)$.

To show that these definitions are equivalent, one must show that $\dim(C_G(g))\ge\mathrm{rank}(G)$ for all $g\in G$ and that there is some element yielding equality.  How can I show these two facts?  Recall that the rank of $G$ is the dimension of a maximal torus $T\subset G$.

Comment: Not every element is in a maximal torus. That is only true in the smooth case for the compact groups for instance. In the general case, even in the algebraic category, an element is in some maximal torus if and only if it acts semisimply on the function ring.

Comment: If you look in James Humphreys' Linear Algebraic Groups, he proves that in a reductive group $G$, for any (connected) maximal torus $T \subseteq H$, $T = C_{G}(t)^{0}$ (superscript refers to connected component) for some element $t \in T$. This should give you an element yielding equality. If I remember exactly which theorem I am citing, I will add a comment.

Comment: It is Proposition 16.4 in that book: it states that for any algebraic group $G$, if $D$ is a torus subgroup of $G$ and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$ stabilize by $D$ under conjugation, then there exists an element $x \in D$ such that $C_{H}(x) = C_{H}(D).$ Apply this to the case where $D$ is a maximal torus (and hence its own centralizer's connected component) and $H = G.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An element need not be in a maximal torus, but in a connect algebraic group over an algebraically closed field, every element $g$ does lie in some Borel subgroup, $B$. Let $U$ be the unipotent radical of $B$. Then $B/U$ is abelian so $(xU)^b = xU$ for all $b \in B$, and so $x^b \in xU$ for all $b \in B$. That means the dimension of the $B$-conjugacy class of $x$ is at most $\dim(U)$, so: $$\dim( C_G(x) ) \geq \dim(  C_B(x) ) = \dim(B) - \dim( x^B ) \geq \dim(B) - \dim(U) = \dim(T) = \operatorname{rank}(G).$$

If $x$ is semisimple, then you can show there is a maximal torus $T$ with $x \in T \leq C_G(x)$, but if $x$ is unipotent then the centralizer is a combination of unipotent and semi-simple elements (and at least to me they look pretty weird; take a regular unipotent element of GL, the centralizer is a triangular Toeplitz matrix).

Comment: Do you assume that $G$ is reductive? Otherwise, how do you define a Borel subgroup? Also, in non-reductive case, the definition of rank is the dimension of maximal self-normalizing nilpotent subalgebra in the Lie algebra. Of course, maybe OP meant reductive groups, I have no idea.

Comment: A Borel subgroup of G is a closed, connected, solvable subgroup B of G which is maximal with respect to all these properties. This does not require reductive. For instance a (connected) solvable group is its own Borel.

Comment: This is page 138-139 of Humphrey's Linear Algebraic Groups.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jack.  This is very clear.